# Web UI for a REST API

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, rest

I wrote a REST API in Node.js (with Express)that implements a queue with some dequeue/enqueue functionality, and the next step is creating a web view for that API.
I am really new to javascript and Node.js , can i have some pointers on how to implement it? is there a framework I can use to integrate the api.js i built with a front-end?

Comment: have your tried angular?

Comment: questions like this usually get closed on stackoverflow because they result in opinionated answers. you can check answers for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072131/frontend-javascript-frameworks-with-node-js though

Comment: A simple google search would give you an answer for this.... I.e. just search for node js test api frontend and you get lots of code examples and tutorials on how its done.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](//meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Comment: @FrankerZ - The question is a bit confusing, that might be right. Dunno. But in contrast to you I think there is quite a standardized way to handle REST APIs backend and frontend side using the MEAN stack (at least as there are quite clean to implement REST standards and as Angular offers a straight ressource service to handle data transfer). In other things I agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

When you wrote a REST api using nodejs and the expressjs framework, you are perfectly prepared to use the complete MEAN stack, which implements angularJS for frontend services.

Angular offers a complete REST implementation (called ngResource). Install via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resource).

With the angular resource service you get your frontend interface (to interact with your backend) out of the box (except a few adaptations you'll have to make, e.g. to make it work with Mongoose, which is used to make the access to your MongoDB more comfortable).

You'll find a few superb tutorials, as [this one](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular) and others on scotch.io are some of them. Google for 'api rest angular resource mean ...' in different selections ;-)

Other links that helped me a lot:

- [Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) from Angular itself
- [Thinkster.io](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#opening-rest-routes) - complete MEAN stack overview with examples
- a helpful [tutorial](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/backend-integration-with-node-express/consuming-rest-apis.html) with good examples from Frederik Dietz
- [Buecheler](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/) comes out with this great tutorial, but its more about the backend side - as you might check your code againt the basic standards of a REST backend implementation.

Those are some of the links I noted and that could find ad hoc.

EDIT:
As your headline suggests you are searching for an UI, I suppose [IBM Strongloop](https://strongloop.com/) might be a good hint for you. IBM is strongly interconnected with the development of ExpressJS and offers this API and UI for probably all data concerning questions of your Webapp.

Comment: I followed the tutorials which served my purpose. thank you

Comment: glad to hear that!